# Azure DataFactory replace espcial characters in Dynamic Content

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a dynamic SQL script that is created with line breaks to make it more readable, but these line breaks are not accepted by Azure Delta Breaks which throws a sitanxis error, is there a way to remove these line breaks? Is it possible to make a replacement?

Dynamic content created in azure data factory:

```
@CONCAT('SELECT ',activity('Get Parameters').output.firstRow.SourceSelectFields,'
 FROM ',activity('Get Parameters').output.firstRow.SourceTable,' ',activity('Get Parameters').output.firstRow.CrossingTables,'
WHERE ',activity('Get Parameters').output.firstRow.Conditions,
' AND doc.status in (''Complete'',''Draft'')',
' AND PRJT.taskname IN ',variables('ListadoTareas'),
' AND (COALESCE (CAST(DATE_FORMAT(cw.begindate,''yyyy-MM-dd'') AS DATE )))> ''',activity('Get Parameters').output.firstRow.BeginDate,'''',
' AND ''',utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd'),''' <= 
CASE WHEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(cw.expirationdate,''yyyy-MM-dd'') AS DATE) !=''1970-01-01'' THEN (CAST(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_FORMAT(cw.expirationdate,''yyyy-MM-dd''),4) AS DATE))
     ELSE CAST(ADD_MONTHS(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(cw.effectivedate,CAST(cw.cus_plazodias_wjcc2 AS INT)),''yyyy-MM-dd''),4)AS DATE)
END',
' AND SUBSTRING(doc.title,1,3) IN ',variables('ListadoDocumentos'),
' AND dl.projectid is null')
```

Line breaks are found in SELECT, FROM and WHERE statements and AND conditions.

Answer (score 0):

- I tried to pass the below script with line breaks as a dynamic content.

```sql
@concat('select ',activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.SourceSelectFields, '
from
',
activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.SourceTable)
```

- When the pipeline is run, Input of the script activity is as in below image.

[image]

- The pipeline run successfully without error.

[image]

But if there is error in the pipeline, try to replace the line breaks with empty string. Below is the approach.

- Variable V1 is taken, and the same script is given.
- In Variable V2, the below expression is given to replace the line break with empty string.

```
@replace(variables('v1'),'
',' ')
```

[image]

**Variable V1 Output**
[image]

**Variable V2 Output**
[image]

- This way, special character line break can be replaced.